# rails - heroku no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I check on internet but every answer to this problem failed on my case.
I'm using ruby on rail and Heroku on Cloud 9 IDE. everything is up to date.

I try to link the Ruby project to Heroku postgres (Postgresql). i followed postgres guide to first understand how it work but when i try to access my localhost, i get this message : `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

I modified pg_hba.conf but it failed so I remove changes

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

in the postgresql.conf I replace Localhost by *

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

on database.yaml i tried to let password empty. currentrly, in production and developpement i let it with "" empty

```
password: ""
```

I tried `sudo service postgresql restart` but still nothing, the issue is still here

I don't know what can i do after that

Answer (score 0):

When using Heroku you should set an ENV variable called `DATABASE_URL` that will take precedence over whatever you add on the database.yml

Comment: this ? the following line come from my database.yaml  :
  database: DATABASE_URL.
and i have a password on Heroku postgres settings, i tried to put it into the password "field". nothing happend still "no password supplied"